# ¿Como mantener el tab activo luego de un submit?

Tags: php, bootstrap, codeigniter, mvc

Estoy programando un sitio con el framework CODE IGNITER y una vista tiene un tab-pane.
Al ingresar la información al formulario y recargar la vista, quedo en el primer tab y necesito poder manejar eso

Alguna sugerencia o idea?

Este es el código de la vista

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">Correo</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Usuarios</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Clientes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#d" data-toggle="tab">Embarques</a>
    </li>
</ul>
...
<div class="tab-pane active" id="b">
    <form class="form-group">
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Luego en mi controlador tengo

```
public function nuevoUsuario(){
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('correoUser', 'Correo', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nUsuario', 'Nombre Usuario', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[50]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data['message'] = validation_errors();
        $this->load->view('Configuracion/config_view',$data);
    }
    else {
        $data = array(
            'usuario' => $this->input->post('correoUser'),
            'nombre' => $this->input->post('nUsuario'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('passUser'),
            'id_perfil' => $this->input->post('perfil')

        );
        $this->Config_model->insertUser($data);
        $data['message'] = 'Datos Ingresados con Exito';
        $this->load->view('Configuracion/config_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Quisiera que al cargar la vista, quede en el tab #b pero no se como manejar ese evento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pueden haber dos caminos posibles

1) Hacer un llamado AJAX a tu funcion de los formularios y asi no recargar la vista. Con esto el tab que estaba activo permanecera tal cual. En el Ajax una vez que recibas un tipo de respuesta (sea correcta o con algun error de codigo, base de datos o restriccion propia de tu logica) puedes manejarla sin problema.

2) La otra es IDENTIFICAR que tab estaba activa.

```
var tabActiva = null;
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
  tabActiva = e.target;
})
```

Asi puedes manejarla una vez que vuelvas del POST.

Comment: muchas gracias :)